# Why should I define stateless function outside of render() method?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm reading doc about redux form and come through this statement:

> You must define the stateless function outside of your render()
> method, or else it will be recreated on every render and will force
> the Field to rerender because its component prop will be different.

And following is the code example:

```
// outside your render() method
const renderField = (field) => (
    <div className="input-row">
      <input {...field.input} type="text"/>
      {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error &&
       <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
  )

// inside your render() method
<Field name="myField" component={renderField}/>
```

My question is, why should I define stateless function outside of render() method? The reason mentioned above is Field will be forced to rerender because component prop will be recreated on every render. But since Field is a Child component, it'll be rerendered anyway even the function is defined outside. Right? I'm new to React. Plz let me know where my understanding goes wrong. Thx!

Comment: When a function is defined inside render method, whenever your component renders, it will define a new function, and your component will be re-rendered. Basically your function will act as a state variable, and it will change with every render. That is why you don't want to define functions inside the render function. When your function is outside, you will avoid unintended re-renders

Comment: @SinanYaman Thx for your reply! Now I got it. I was curious what's the problem of rendering Field, since Field is a Child component, it'll be rendered anyway. Now I realized the problem is rerendering. Field will be rendered again if stateless function is defined inline.